# Largest consecutive number of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cs50, dna-sequence

Consider the following Lavender DNA Sequence:

```
GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCCCGTCAACTCATTCACACCGCATCCTTTCCTGCCACTGTAACTAGTCGACTGGGGAACCTCATCATCCATACTCTCCCACATTATGCCTCCCAACCTTGTTAAGCGTGGCATGCTTGGGATTGCATTGATGCTTCTTGGAGAGGACGCTTTCGTTTTGGAGATTACAGGGATCCAATTTTATCATCGGTTCGACTCCCGTAACGACTTAGCAGTAAGGGTGCTAGTTCCTGGTTAGAATCTTAATAAATCACGTCGCTTGGAGCAAGACAAAGATCGTCGTAATGCCAAGTGCACGACCACCTTCAGACTTGCAGGACCCGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTCGATAGCTATGCGGTTCAATACAATCTTAACGCAATGCAGCGATGTGGTTTCGTACACTTAGCATAAAACCCCCCACATTAAATCGATGTACCCGCCCTCTTAGACGCCAATTTCAATGCCGAACCTCCGGCGGGTATCTCTGCACTAGGAGAAGTAGCACGTCGCTGTAGCGAACTCCTATCGTGAGATAATTTGTAGAGCTGCTCTTATAATACAATAGCTCAGATGGATTATTCCATGGACATCCCCGTGCGTTGTTTCGAGGATGGTAGGTGGAAATTTTGCCAGACCTCTAGTCTTAAACATGGTTGACGTTATAGGCGCTATCTCTTGCGTCTGGAAGTGTTAATCCGTGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACACGCAACTCTGGAGGAGGGCACTGCACTGCAAACTTGCGTAATATCCTTCACCCACACTTGCCTGGCCTCCTTGCTTAAAGCTCTGGCGATGCGATTTTTCGGCCCAGTAGCTGAATAGGTCATGAAATGGGCACCGAACTGGAAAGACCCATATATTCGATACTCACAACTTAATGATAGCGCGATTAAGAGCGACACCAAAAACCAAATTACGTTCACGAACCTTTGAGAGTCAAGGAGACTTAGACCGAATTGAATGATCACTGATGCGCCCGCTGATACTGAGCCTCACCATTAATCGCCGACCAATACGGCGTGTACCGGGCGCGGCCTTGCCGCATAACGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATATCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTACACAGCCCCGTCCTCATTGCTAAGTGCACTGGCAACTGGACCTAAAGATTTTTCGAGTATGGCCCTCGAATCAAGCGCCCACCCAGAAACCTACGAGCCAGTAACCCCAGTAAACAAGCATTAGTGCTATATGCTTGCTGCCCACTAGGACCCTTATGGTTCATACCAGGGTGACGTGTCTTGCGGGCCAAGGATGAACCAGAAGCAAGATCCTTAGATGGACGACTGTCTCATTGCTTAAACTCCACATACCAAAGGGCGCGGTAAACGATAGTTTTAGGTAATGTTAGTCGGATGGTTGTCTGCAGCTACCAATACAGCCTGGCACCCAGGGTCTGAACAATAACGCGTGAGAGCAGCTCTCCCGCGTGTGGTGGATTTGCCGTCTATGAAATTGAGGCTCTTGCAACTATTCGCACTCGGAATGCCCTCATATCTGGTGCCTAGCGGCCTTTGCCCCGTGCCGGTAGGACTAAACTCTACGGATCGTTGACGGATCTCGATGTGGAAGATGGTTATGAAAGATAACAACGCGTGTGCTAATTGATTTAGACAAGTATTGCGGCAGTAAAAGATAATCGGCTGCAGAGTTACGAAAGACTTCCATGCATGGATTCCATTCCTTCTAGTATAGGACCCACTCTGAATACACGTCTTGCGGGCCGATCATCTCCACCGCTGCGGAAGAAAGCAATTAAGAATCTATGCTCATTAAGAGTGCGACTATAATGCGGATCTTACAGTGCTAATGATCAGGACGTCGTCCAAGCAGGCTGCATGCCGAATTTAGCTTACGTCAGGATCAGGCGTTATAGCCTGGGAATCGGACTATGAGGACGCCACGACCTCTGGGAGAAAGCTATATACATTGAGGATCGCGCCATCTTTATGAGACTCAAATGAATCTAGATAGGTAGCATTGCGGACTTGAGTTAGCACATCGGTATTGGAAGGTGAGGGTCCTGCCGCTCGTTCTATGTTCGGTTTATAGTATACAAATAGGTCATCCCGAACGTTGAAGTTAAACTCATGACACGTTGTCGTAATGAAACGGGCCTGTTATTAGGGATACAGACAAAAGGCACAAGCTGGCTTGCACATTAAGGCGCACTAGAGATCCTCACAACCGTTGCCCGCACGGAGGTCGTGTCTAACAGACAGTGAACCAGCCGTATTGGGGTGGATGACCTGAGCTTCTTGGGGCCTGTTGTACACCGCGTGTGGTTCAACTGGTACACATACTACGAATATTCGAAATCATTGTACTGTGCTCTTCGGTGCTACTGACTGTGAGCGAATGCATCCCAATCCCAAACAATGCTTGTGGTAGGAGAATTGAAACTCTCGAAGCCTGGCCCAATGTCATCTACTTTTAACATGTCGGGCCAGGAGTTACGGGCATTGCTTACTTACTTTGCCCCCTTACACCACAGCAGCGCGATTCTTGTTGTAGTAGATTTTATACGACTCGCGAATTAAATGGAACTTGTCTGTCCCATATCGATCGTGTCCATCGTAAGATGAGATTGTAGGAGCATTCGGAAGTCTATGCGGCCCAGGGACTACTACGTTAAATCTGGTCAGACGTGGTTTACAAGGCGTCCCGATCTTCTCAGAACATATGGGAAAGCACTACCGTTCCTTCACGCATACAGTTGTTCGTGCCGAACGAGTAAGCTTGCGACCAGCCCACCCGCTAGGGCTATGCAGCGGGTCATGGCTGGCGCCATACTGTGCGGACAACCCACGCTCTGGCAGAAAGCGTCTTGTGTTTTGTAGTAGCTCCAACGGTTAGACCTTCGATATCTATTCAGAGCGCGAGCGACCACTATTAGACGGCATGTAAACAATGTGTATTTGTTCGGCCCAACCGGTATATGGGTAAGACCGCGAAGGGCCTGCGCGAATACCAGCGTCCAAAAATTCCTCACCCGAGATATGCGGTTAGTACCCCTTGGGTAACGGTCCGCTACGGGTAGCGACGCGAGCCGGCCGCATCGGTTGGAGCCGAGTTGTCGGGCAGGCGAGTAACGTGTGCAATTTGATGGGCCCAAGCCTCCGGCACTATCCACCTCATACATCGACAAAAGCACCAAATATGGGGAAAAGCTGAGCGTCGATATGTACATCTACCCAGGAACCGGCCCGAACATTAGGCGGACGTGAATTTCCGACCTAGGTTCGGCTACATTTCTACGATCCAAGCACACGTGAAGGAGGAGGGGTGTTCCGACCGTAAATGAACGAGGTGCGCAGTGACCCGATGGCGTTTAGCGGATAGCCTTCCTATGCCGGCCTATGCTGTATGGTAGTTGGTTGGTGCCTCCAGAGCCACTGCACCCAATCATAGGGTCTACAGCAGCGTACTTATAAAATTGTACGGGTGACCCATATCCATTACGGGTTGCGACCAGTATAGGAGAGTATAACTGCGTGAACTAATGCGTTATGACGCTTCAGAGTTTGCTCGGGCCCGAGTTCTAGGGCTATAATGTGTTAGGGCGCAAGTATGCCAAGCTAAGATGTGGCGTGCACACTAGGAGTTGTGTTCCTCTGCAAGCAGACACGAGCACTCTGGCAGTAGTTTGACCACACCCGGGTATCACTGCTACTCCATTTCGAACAAGCTATTGGAGCGGACAAAATATGCTACTCAAGAGCATTAGTTATAGGTCTACGAGACAGAAGCAGTTACTGAGTCTGAATATTCGATATAAGTAGGCATGGAGGCGGAGCAAAACAACGTCTGCGATCAATCGTGTTGATGACGTATGGCGACTGGAAGGTAAGGACTATGGCCGGACGGAATGATTCATGTTCTGTTCAAAGCTATATTTCGAAGGGGTATATTAGCGGTCCTACACTTGGTTAGCACCCTCCCCCCTCTGGATCCTGCACTAATTCGAGCTGGCCTCCATCGGTATCAGTCCGGAAGCTCCACTCTCTATCGTAGTCCTAATCAACAGGGTGCCAGTTTGCTCACGTGGAAGTTTGAGGCCCTTTGTGCTCCATAGCCAATCACTAACCATGCACGCGCGACCCACTCTACGTCCAGATCGGCTATAATAGTTGCGCCCGGGACTGGCAGAGTAGACATGTAAGCTAGATAGAGCCCCGACATCGGCCAAGAGATCCTACGCTGCTTCCAGATAATGAGAGACATTCTAGCATTAGACATGCAAGTCGGCAGGGACTCCCCTTATCTAGTAATTTCGATGAATTGGTTTTTCGGCTAGCATCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGACCATGCCGACCTCATCATAGAAGGAATGCTCTAAACTTAGAGTGCTACTAGGAAAACTATTAATCAATGATCGTCCTGCTTACATAGCTGGACGGCGAAAGTTCTTATACTGCGGAGGTTGCTGACGTAGAGTGCGCTGGGTACAGCGGATAAGTTGATCAGGGTGGGGATAGGGTGGCTCACCGTTTATACTCATATAGATTCCTGGCGTCGACGCTGTGACAGGGTCGAGATCGAGGGGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGCGGAGCGGAGGGAAAATTATCACCAGAGGGTAGGGGCTCGCGACATTCTATTCAATGCATTTCAAGCTACTTACGTATTTCGGCACAGTGACTACTGCCTGCGCGGCAGCCGTAAGGTTTCCCGTCAATAGGTGGCACGTATCATTGATGAAAGTGTCAGCTAATCATTCAGGCCTTA
```

and this dictionary

```
sqc_large_dictionary = ["AGATC","TTTTTTCT","AATG","TCTAG","GATA","TATC","GAAA","TCTG"]
```

That are the words we have to look for in Lavender's DNA sequence.

The problem is that, for example, I have managed with re and collections to create an algorithm that detects all AATG's (66). But the spec tells me that I should only count the longest consecutive sequence, in this case 43, since the others are watered, but there are 43 AATGs that are one behind the other and that is the number I should take. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can split the sequence by the elements so you get sth like this:

```
lst = ['ATG','ATG','ATG','ATG','ATG','asd','ATG']
```

You can use:

```
from itertools import groupby
for a, g in groupby(lst):
    print(a, len(list(g)))

ATG 5
asd 1
ATG 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the sequence, then group and finally and get the max.

```
>>> sequences = re.findall(str.join('|',sqc_large_dictionary),l)
>>> groups = [(k,len(list(grp))) for k,grp in itertools.groupby(sequences)]
>>> max(groups, key=lambda x:x[1])
('GAAA', 47)
```

To get the max for each sequence type you can do:

```
>>> res = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in groups:
...     res[k] = max(res[k], v)
... 
>>> res
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'TCTG': 41, 'GATA': 27, 'AATG': 42, 'GAAA': 47, 'TATC': 19, 'AGATC': 23, 'TTTTTTCT': 33, 'TCTAG': 12})
```

Comment: l is the string with the dna sequence

Comment: Mmm, this is working for me, but for some reason, some numbers do not match by 1 number in the database. According to my database: Lavender AGATC 22 TTTTTTCT 33 AATG 43 TCTAG 12 GATA 26 TATC 18 GAAA 47 TCTG 41